# Count columns int the file

Tags: batch-file

I need help. I have to count columns .txt using batch file. The columns are Delimited by "|"
I'm trying this:

```
@echo off

set file=C:\Users\Documents\test\days.txt

for /F "delims==|" %%a in ('type "%file%" ^|find "" /v /c') do set contColumns=%%a    

echo This file %file% have %contColumns% columns.

PAUSE
```

Comment: It would help of we had details of the input files. Also are the number of columns the same on each line? _Reading in the first line only is better than reading all_.

Answer (score 2):

The following will compute the number of `|` delimited columns found in the first line of your file. This will only work if the line length is <= 1021, and the lines are Windows format (terminated by \r\n), not Unix format (terminated by \n).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file=C:\Users\Documents\test\days.txt"

:: Read the first line
set "ln="
<"%file%" set /p "ln="

:: Convert columns into lines by substituting .\n. for every |
if defined ln set ^"ln=.!ln:^|=.^
%= This equates to a newline (\n) character =%
.!^"

:: Count the number of lines and store the result
for /f %%N in ('cmd /v:on /c echo(^^!ln^^!^|find /c /v ""') do set "cnt=%%N"

echo line 1 column count = %cnt%
```

If lines can exceed 1021 or are not terminated by \r\n, but are < 8191, then

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file=C:\Users\Documents\test\days.txt"

:: Read the first line
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%file%") do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  goto :endLoop
)
:endLoop

:: Convert columns into lines by substituting .\n. for every |
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if defined ln set ^"ln=.!ln:^|=.^
%= This equates to a newline (\n) character =%
.!^"

:: Count the number of lines and store the result
for /f %%N in ('cmd /v:on /c echo(^^!ln^^!^|find /c /v ""') do set "cnt=%%N"

echo line 1 column count = %cnt%
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q426111659.txt"

:: get first line
SET /p line=<"%filename1%"

:: remove all spaces, commas and semicolons
SET "line=%line: =%"
SET "line=%line:,=%"
SET "line=%line:;=%"
:: convert all pipes to spaces and count
SET /a count=0
FOR %%a  IN (%line:|= %) DO SET /a count+=1

ECHO %count% columns IN file


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q426111659.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Read the first line of the file into `line`.

Replace all spaces, commas and semicolons in the line with *nothing*. Theoretically, you'd need to replace <kbd>Tab</kbd> as well - the formula is `set "varname=%varname:replacethis=withthis%"`

Finally, replace each pipe with a space and count the resultant number of tokens.